# Error 500 in apt-cache policy

Tags: package-management, synaptics, apt-cache

I have installed jasper using synaptic manager. When I tried to check the version using:

```
apt-cache policy jasper
```

this was displayed:

```
jasper:   Installed: (none)   
Candidate: 0.69   
Version table:      0.69 0         
500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

I installed the software using synaptic manager. Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

It is not **error** 500. It is **priority** 500. From `man apt-cache`:

> **policy** [pkg...]
>
> > policy is meant to help debug issues relating to the preferences
> >                file. With no arguments it will print out the priorities of each
> >                source. Otherwise it prints out detailed information about the
> >                priority selection of the named package.